# Swift - function paramter of type Data can't be stored in local state variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, init

```
    @State private var selectedPhotoData: Data?

    init(friendID: String, friendUsername: String, friendName: String, friendBio: String, friendSelectedPhotoData: Data?) {
        
        self.id = friendID
        self.username = friendUsername
        self.name = friendName
        self.bio = friendBio
        self.selectedPhotoData = friendSelectedPhotoData

        print(friendSelectedPhotoData) //prints Optional(394546 bytes)
        print(selectedPhotoData) //prints nil
    }
```

**Why is selectedPhotoData not equal to friendSelectedPhotoData?** I explicitly have:

```
self.selectedPhotoData = friendSelectedPhotoData
```

Comment: try this: `_selectedPhotoData = State(initialValue: friendSelectedPhotoData)` to initialise a State var in init.

Comment: That worked - thanks so much! Can you please explain why? 
`self.id = friendID` works but `self.selectedPhotoData = friendSelectedPhotoData` doesn't.

Comment: have a look at the duplicate link, there are some explanations there.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles on this:

- for string, int, etc - direct assignment works. eg: self.id = friendID 

- for custom object - use State(initialValue: ). eg: _selectedPhotoData = State(initialValue: friendSelectedPhotoData)

- for arrays, use @ Binding and in this case, no init needed

Feel free to add anything else if needed @workingdogsupportUkraine